# PDAL How to use "ogr" option in "readers.copc"

Tags: pdal

How can I use the "ogr" option in "readers.copc"?

My pipeline is :

```
[
    {
        "type":"readers.copc",
        "ogr": [{
            "drivers": "ESRI Shapefile",
            "layer":"\\\\my_server\\my_folder\\my_subfolder\\my_layer.shp"
            }]
    },
    {
        "type": "writers.las",
        "forward": "all"
    }

]
```

Verbose said : "PDAL: [json.exception.out_of_range.403] key 'datasource' not found"

Maybe it's not so simple as "write a file path" but I tried many things and I can't find how to do it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need `datasource` to point to the shapefile instead of `layer`. See the [PDAL test suite](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/blob/master/test/unit/io/CopcReaderTest.cpp#L621) for inspiration.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. Sorry I didn't react sooner. I'll try it later.

Comment: Sorry Howard, but it didn’t help me.
I can’t understand how to use the pdal test for inspiration. I just used « datasource » instead of « layer ».
The verbose is : « [json exception.type-error.302] type must be array but is string. »
What makes me even more confused is that PDAL’s guide don’t talk about « datasource ». https://pdal.io/en/2.6.3/stages/readers.copc.html
ogr option arguments are given as : 
{   "drivers":
     "openoptions":
    "layer": 
    "sql": 
    "options":
    {
        "geometry", "WKT or GeoJSON geomtry used to filter query [optional]"
    }
}
Thank you